# Split comma separated Id value and select the corresponding value from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following two tables

### Team

```
Id      Members
+++     +++++++
1       8,9,15,13
2       1,2,5,9,11
```

### Users

```
Id      Username
+++     ++++++++
1       Admin
2       Test 
3       another user
```

I need the result to be like this:

### Final result

```
Id        Team
++++++    ++++++
1         Admin,test user, new user
2         sweet user, nice user, keep looking user
```

I use the following query but the problem it is a subquery and it does not return one row:

```
SELECT [Id]
      ,[Username] as Manager
,[Teams].[Name]
      ,[Teams].[Description]
      ,(

       select ', '+T1.Username
       from [Users] as T1
       where ','+T2.Memebers+',' like '%,'+cast(T1.UserID as varchar(10))+',%'
       for xml path(''), type
       ).value('substring(text()[1], 3)', 'varchar(max)') as Memebers
from [Metarabia_Teams] as T2
      ) as Memebers
  FROM [dbo].[Teams],[dbo].[Users]
  where [Teams].[ManagerId] = [DNNTest].[dbo].[Users].UserID
```

Comment: Stroing foreign keys as csv is very bad db layout

Comment: @Jens I see but how can I store them?

Comment: You should really normalize your Team table : a relationship user_team table should replace your `members` comma separated fields.

Comment: I've already wrote this today once: keeping comma separated values in relational database should be outlawed.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus okay what is the way to do this?

Comment: Well : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model) , then you'll have enough keywords to google successfully ;)

Comment: Add another table storing MemberID and TeamID for each valid combination. So you will have three tables: Members, Team and TeamMembers for instance.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to replace the ids with the names by first splitting the data into rows and then putting it back together. This is of course a really bad way of doing things, you should rather have the data stored so that one column contains one id / name, and not multiple things.

```
select t.id, isnull(u.username,'Missing: ' + l.item) as Name
into #tmp
from team t
cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(members, ',') l
left outer join users u on u.id = l.item

SELECT id, STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Name 
  FROM #tmp AS t2
   WHERE t2.id = t.id 
   FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') as Names
FROM #tmp AS t
GROUP BY id
```

This requires that you have a string splitting function, for example [DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) by Jeff Moden.

You can test this in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/80793).

If the user is missing, the SQL adds 'Missing' + the user id instead of the name.

Answer (score 0):

we can achieve this by using Cross Apply and XML Path() .basing on your assumpted data i have provided Result Set

```
declare @t table (Id int,Members varchar(20))
insert into @t (Id,Members)values (1,'8,9,15,13'),(2,'1,2,5,9,11')

declare @tt table (Id int,username varchar(20))
insert into @tt(Id,username)values 
(1,'Admin'),
(2,'Test'),
(3,'Anotheruser'),
(5,'niceuser'),
(4,'nice'),
(5,'niceuser'),
(6,'helper')
,(7,'quite'),
(8,'just'),
(9,'not'),
(11,'keeplookinguser'),
(13,'lookinguser'),
(15,'keepRocking')

;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT   Id,
     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS String  
 FROM  (SELECT ID,  
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([Members], ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
     FROM  @t) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a))

  ,CTE2 as (          
SELECT t.Id, STUFF((SELECT ', ' + T2.username 
  FROM @tt AS t2
   WHERE t2.id = t.String 
   FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') as Names
FROM CTE AS t
GROUP BY id,string )
SELECT DISTINCT t.Id, STUFF((SELECT ', ' + T2.Names 
  FROM CTE2 AS t2
   WHERE t2.id = t.id 
   GROUP BY id,Names 
   ORDER BY names DEsc
   FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') as Names
FROM CTE2 AS t
```